# Amazon AWS Lambda: Cannot find "Request"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I'm using the AWS Lambda Function in the Amazon AWS Online-Builder.
I'm using nodejs 6.10. and I want to require the reuest module with `var test = require("request")`. But the response is: `"errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'request'",`
I'm also including the module http with `var http = require('http');` and this works. Anyone an idea, why I cannot require "`request`"? THANKS!

Comment: have you added request module in package.json?

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have package.json in your code or not?

Comment: npm install request --save

Comment: I'm using the Amazon AWS Web console. Where can I send a terminal request like npm install

Comment: @Rahul Sharma I have one: {
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "request": "latest"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  }
}

Answer (score 3):

You need to have add a dependency for the request module in your package.json file. Something like:

"dependencies": {
    "request": "2.88.0"
  }

There is a good description of how to add node modules to a function at https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/948